# will _paginate not paging with SEQUEL

Tags: ruby, will-paginate, sequel

I am struggling with this. Using sinatra, ruby and Sequel, I attempting to implement paging.

The query is:

```
@items = DB[:candidates].order(:id).paginate(1, 10)
```

which works,it produces the desired number of records and the <%= will_paginate(@items) %> link generates the following HTML:

```
← Previous 1 2 3 4 5 Next →
```

When I click on the number or next link in my browser address bar I get, for exampl:

```
http://localhost:4567/candidate?page=3`
```

but the page does not change!

The ruby code is:

```
get '/candidate' do
      @items = DB[:candidates].order(:id).paginate(1, 10)
      erb :candidate
end
```

Any ideas? All help gratefully received. Is there a problem with param passing? The query

```
@items = DB[:candidates].order(:id).paginate(page: params[:page], 10)
```

does not work and produces an error message.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

write the following code

```
@items = DB[:candidates].order(:id).paginate(:page=>params[:page] || 1, :per_page => 10)
```

and i the view file You write
   <%= will_paginate @items, :container => false %>
instead of

```
@items = DB[:candidates].order(:id).paginate(1, 10)
```

And it works

Comment: thank you, unfortunately it does not. This is the error:

ArgumentError at /candidate
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

    file: pagination.rb
    location: paginate
    line: 17

Comment: <% @items.each do |item| %>
<td><%= item[:designation] %></td> etc, other fields
<% end %>
<tr><td colspan="6"><%= will_paginate(@items) %></td></tr>

Comment: you write <%= will_paginate @items, :container => false %> in place of <%= will_paginate(@items) %>

Comment: thank you, same problem. Error message is: ArgumentError at /candidate
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

Comment: http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2010/8/22/revisited-roll-your-own-pagination-links-with-will_paginate-and-rails-3 this link

Comment: thank you, I have seen something very similar already. It seems to be for active record rather than sequel. Am I wrong? I will study it again nonetheless.